# Disable interactive grid columns based on date items

Tags: oracle-apex-19.1

In apex 19.1 i have an interactive grid region and static region which two date picker items which are populated with week start and end date in a month. how can i disable edit on few columns based on date. For example lets say i have col1-col7 in my interactive grid and selected start date is wednesday and end date is sunday then col1.col2 should not allow user to edit them but the user should be able to edit col3-col7. similarly when start date is monday and end date is thursday then user should be able to edit from col1-col4 only. This criteria should be applied even when user applies filters on grid and when user adds new records.

I have tried read only section in column attributes with server side condition but it didn't work. If you know any approach pley let me know